# Javascript .removeChild() only deletes even nodes?

Tags: javascript

I am trying dynamically add children DIV under a DIV with ID="prnt". Addition of nodes work fine no problem. However strange enough when it comes to deleted nodes its only deleting the even numbered nodes including 0. Why is this, I could be something stupid but it seem more like a bug. I could be very wrong.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function displayNodes()
        {
            var prnt = document.getElementById("prnt");
            var chlds = prnt.childNodes;
            var cont = document.getElementById("content");

            for(i = 0; i < chlds.length; i++)
            {
                if(chlds[i].nodeType == 1)
                {

                    cont.innerHTML +="<br />";
                    cont.innerHTML +="Node # " + (i+1);
                    cont.innerHTML +="<br />";
                    cont.innerHTML +=chlds[i].nodeName;
                    cont.innerHTML +="<br />";

                }
            }
        }

        function deleteENodes()
        {
            var prnt = document.getElementById("prnt");
            var chlds = prnt.childNodes;


            for(i = 0; i < chlds.length; i++)
            {

                    if(!(chlds[i].nodeType == 3))
                    {
                        prnt.removeChild(chlds[i]);
                    }

            }


        }

        function AddENodes()
        {
            var prnt = document.getElementById("prnt");

           //Only even nodes are deletable PROBLEM

            for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {

                var newDIV = document.createElement('div');
                newDIV.setAttribute("id", "c"+(i));

                var text = document.createTextNode("New Inserted Child "+(i));
                newDIV.appendChild(text);
                prnt.appendChild(newDIV);

            }
        }

    </script>

    <title>Checking Div Nodes</title>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="prnt">
        Parent 1

    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

   <button type="button" onclick="displayNodes()">Show Node Info</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="deleteENodes()">Remove All Element Nodes Under Parent 1</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="AddENodes()">Add 5 New DIV Nodes</button>

    <div id="content">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The arrays returned by many DOM mathods (childNodes, getElementsByTagName, etc) are "live": they are magically updated whenever the document changes. This can lead to subtle bugs like the one you are experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're modifying the collection as you loop through it.  Iterating in reverse should fix this...

```
for(i = chlds.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(!(chlds[i].nodeType == 3))
    {
         prnt.removeChild(chlds[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do away with the  if(!(chlds[i].nodeType == 3)) nodeType check.

You can pull only the divs by doing a .querySelectorAll('div')

```
function deleteENodes()
        {

 var chlds = document.getElementById("prnt").querySelectorAll('div');<----


            for(i = 0; i < chlds.length; i++)
            {

                    if(!(chlds[i].nodeType == 3))
                    {
                        prnt.removeChild(chlds[i]);
                    }

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as you're deleting nodes (starting from the beginning), the index of the remaining child nodes is decreasing by one each time:

Given 5 children:

```
Child1 Index0
Child2 Index1
Child3 Index2
Child4 Index3
Child5 Index4
```

When you go to remove them, this is what is happening

```
.removeChild(0) removes Child1
Child2 is now Index0
Child3 is now Index1
....

next Iteration:
.removeChild(1) removes Child3
Child2 is still Index0
Child4 is now Index1
Child5 is now Index2
....
```

Solution. Remove children from last index and move towards 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `NodeList` returned by `childNodes` is "live" - removing a child updates the list immediately.

What's happening is that you're removing an element, which decreases the length of the list by 1, causing your loop to skip an element.

One way to avoid this is by copying the elements into an`Array`.

E.g.

```
var nodes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < chlds.length; i++) {
  nodes.push(chlds[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
  if(!(nodes[i].nodeType == 3))
  {
    prnt.removeChild(nodes[i]);
  }
}
```